# Trouble installing gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme, dependency/PPA conflict?

Tags: package-management, ppa, dependencies, gnome-tweak-tool

I installed gnome tweak tool, and am trying to set up custom themes and whatnot. So, trying to install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme.

```
me@computer:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
[sudo] password for me: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme : Depends: gnome-shell-extensions-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Not going to be installed? Okay, let's see about that...

```
me@computer:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-shell-extensions-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Wait, what? Broken packages? Ruh Roh! Seems to me it might be a PPA contradiction problem or something, but I'm tired of trashing my installs. Kinda lost here. Any ideas?

Output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

```
drex@U110:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: @BasharatSial I assume -f means force? Results in edit of original question.

Comment: yup , try what he said . only sudo apt-get install -f . :)

Comment: Oh...  See secondary Edit.

Comment: @Drex Which PPA did you added to get this package?

Comment: @BasharatSial I beleive it was ppa:webupd8team/gnome3

Comment: @Drex Well it's giving same error to me, May be this package hasn't been updated for 12.04. You can contact [WebUpd8” team](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team)

Comment: @BasharatSial  Alright, I was beginning to assume the same. Thank you for your help, either way! On to Cinnamon...  :)

Answer (score 1):

yeah...this happened again today. This output tells you, that the developers are again working on gnome-shell and so you should look for updates in Terminal more often on such days.

Then after getting update and upgrade, go to your Synaptic, refresh it completely and then try to install.

If this output comes again, then you just need to wait to a later time...